# Running the same for loop on many GPU threads, using OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu, pyopencl

I need to subtract a 2D array, `D`, from many other different 2D arrays. I have linearized (flattened) all the arrays: `D` is a 25-element array, and `imges` is a 1D array were 4 25-element arrays have been joined together. Meaning: if I want to subtract `D` from 4 5x5 arrays, I'm just turning each one of those 5x5 arrays into one 25-element array, and then appending the 4 arrays. That's what `imgs` is, in this example it would be a 100-element array. I believe I am capturing this properly in my kernel, index-wise.

The only way that has come to mind to do the subtraction is to run a `for` loop, so that every element from `D` will get subtracted from the array in the corresponding thread. My idea was that this would work as follows:

1. Each thread would receive the `D` array to be subtracted, and one of the arrays from which `D` has to be subtracted from (in my example, 1/4 of `imges`)
2. I would iterate through the elements of both arrays with a for loop to do the subtraction element by element

However, it is not working as expected: it seems like just the last or first value of `D` gets chosen and then subtracted from all the elements of the other arrays.

I thought I had a hang of how indexing and threading worked on GPU, but now I am not so sure since this has been challenging me for a while. The kernel is below.

Is there a better way to do this other than with a for loop? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
__kernel void reduce(__global float* D, __global float* imges, __global float* res)
{
    const int x = (int)get_global_id(0);
    const int y = (int)get_global_id(1);
    const int z = (int)get_global_id(2);

    int im_i = imges[x+25]; //Images are 5x5 meaning a 25-size array

   for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
       res[x+25] = im_i - D[j];
   }
}
```

**Edit:** I do not wish to parallelize the `for` loop itself, since the arrays will probably get bigger and I don't want to run into trouble with overhead.

Comment: What is `dark`, is that supposed to be `D`?

Comment: @jprice yes, changed it to `D` to make it simpler and forgot to change it there. Edited.

Comment: res[x+25] = im_i - D[j];  --->  res[x+25] += im_i - D[j]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, your kernel should look more like this:

```
__kernel void reduce(__global float* D, __global float* imges, __global float* res)
{
  const int x = (int)get_global_id(0);

  for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
    res[x*25 + j] = imges[x*25 + j] - D[j];
  }
}
```

This kernel will subtract the `j`th element of `D` from the `j`th element of each work-item's 25-element array in `imges`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Can't believe I wasn't actually "iterating" over the image.